# Docker & Postgres: Failed to bind tcp 0.0.0.0:5432 address already in use

Tags: macos, postgresql, docker

### Problem

I'm trying to start postgres in a docker container on my Mac, but I keep getting the following error message

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint postgres (8392b9e5cfaa28f480fe1009dee461f97e82499726f4afc4e916358dd2d2f61e): Error starting userland proxy: Failed to bind tcp 0.0.0.0:5432 address already in use.

I have postgres installed locally, but I stopped it and running

```
pg_ctl status
```

returns

> pg_ctl: no server running

I've ran the following to check what's running on 5432

```
lsof -i tcp:5432
```

&

```
netstat -anp tcp | grep 5432
```

and nothing is running on the port.

### Versions

Mac - OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.2

PostgreSQL - 9.5

Docker - Docker version 1.12.0-rc2, build 906eacd, experimental

Comment: Same here. working fine for me locally but failing on travis ci. i'm using 1.11.2 with compose 1.7.1.

Answer (score 153):

If `lsof -i :5432` doesn't show you any output, you can use `sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :5432'` to see what process is bound to the port.

Proceed further with `kill <pid>`

Comment: With this command I get "sudo: ss: command not found" - any idea what is causing that?

Comment: It appears that system-wide Postgres service is running on that port. First we kill it and then allow docker-compose occupy that port.

Comment: Use the following command to get the processes: sudo lsof -i :5432

Comment: Running `sudo lsof -i :5432` then `kill <pid>` worked for me.

Comment: you need to use `kill -9 pid` for macos

Comment: sudo lsof -i tcp:5432

Comment: If you use MacOS 12 Monterey or 13 Ventura, and you try to run postgres DB in Docker on port 5000, you may see the error `"Cannot start service postgres-db: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use"`. It's because port 5000 is already used by a system app called "Control Center". Check with `lsof -i :5000`. You have to change the postgres port number. See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332 and https://nono.ma/port-5000-used-by-control-center-in-macos-controlce and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431154

Comment: Thanks a lot. Spent lot of time to figure out this issue. Didn't even expect that postgres is running with sudo... Hats off to you

Answer (score 60):

If you execute `lsof -i :5432` on the host you can see what process is bound to the port.

[image]

Some instance of Postgres is running. You can execute `kill <pid>` to kill it if you want. You can also use `5432` instead of `5432:5432` in your docker command or docker-compose file and let docker choose the host port automatically.

Comment: HI this is old but I tried ur suggestion by changing the 5432:5432 to just 5432 in docker-compose.yml file. But it still gives the same error.

Comment: do you have any output for `sudo lsof -i :5432`?

Comment: That thing got resolved. Wud u be able to help with this issue? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109965/superset-loading-issue-on-ubuntu

Comment: @blockloop yes i see one postgres process with pid 144 running.

Comment: run sudo lsof -i :5432, and then run kill <PID>

Comment: It's necessary to run the command as super user.

Answer (score 48):

The first thing you should do is stop PostgreSQL service.
In most cases it fixed the issue.

```sh
sudo service postgresql stop
```

If above doesn't work. then add the following line to `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`

```sh
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf

## good if you add under CONNECTION AND AUTHENTICATION comments
listen_addresses = "*"
```

Answer (score 38):

**macOS Monterey**

None of the above commands worked for me - need to do few changes. So, adding the complete working solution:

1. Identify what is running in port 5432: `sudo lsof -i :5432`
2. Kill all the processes that are running under this port: `sudo kill -9 <pid>`
3. Run the command again to verify no process is running now: `sudo lsof -i :5432`

[image]

Answer (score 10):

it is worked for me, probably you should stop postgres :

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it is critical to perform a more in-depth debugging to the problem before stopping or killing the container/process.

Consider following the checklist below:

1) **Check you current docker compose environment** 
 Run `docker-compose ps`.
 If port is in use by another container, stop it with `docker-compose stop <service-name-in-compose-file>` or remove it by replacing `stop` with `rm`.

2) **Check the containers running outside your current workspace** 
Run `docker ps` to see list of all containers running under your host.
If you find the port is in use by another container, you can stop it with `docker stop <container-id>`. 
(*) Because you're not under the scope of the origin `compose` environment - it is a good practice first to use [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) to gather more information about the container that you're about to stop.

3) **Check if port is used by other processes running on the host**
For example if the port is 6379 run:

```
$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':6379'
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      915/redis-server 12 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6379                :::*                    LISTEN      915/redis-server 12
```

(*)  You can also use the [lsof](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) command which is mainly used to retrieve information about files that are opened by various processes (I suggest running `netstat` before that).

So, In case of the output above the `PID` is `915`. Now you can run:

```
$ ps j 915
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
    1   915   915   915 ?           -1 Ssl    123   0:11 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

And see the ID of the parent process (`PPID`) and the execution command.
You can also run: `$ pstree -s <PID>` to a visual display of the process and its related processes (install with: `brew install pstree`).

In our case we can see that the process probably is a daemon (PPID is 1) - In that case consider running: 
 A) `$ cat /proc/<PID>/status` in order to get a more in-depth information about the process like the number of threads spawned by the process, its capabilities, etc'.
B) `$ systemctl status <PID>` in order to see the [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) unit that caused the creation of a specific process. If the service is not critical - you can [stop and disable the service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units).

4) **Restart Docker service** 
Run `sudo service docker restart`.

5) **You reached this point and..** 
Only if its not placing your system at risk - consider restarting the server.

Answer (score 3):

None of these other answers worked for me. (For example, lsof and netstat just returned empty lines.) The following worked, though:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data stop
```

Comment: using mac os iterm i got this response: `sudo: pg_ctl: command not found`

Comment: Might have to change 13 to your version of postgres, but this worked for me on mac

Answer (score 2):

In case of mac,

- **if you are OK with uninstalling the POSTGRES for the time being:**

```
brew uninstall postgres
```

Then check if the process still exists

```
sudo lsof -nP -i4TCP:5432 | grep LISTEN
```

If it exists, then kill it

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Check again if the 5432 is being listened at, this time it should not be.

Answer (score 2):

This command line is very simple and easy to remember, using third party javascript packages. npx comes built in with Node.js:

```
npx kill-port 3000
```

For a more powerful tool with search:

```
npx fkill-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS:

```
sudo lsof -i:5432
```

1. This should output a list of processes listening on port 5432 - which is the default Postgresql server port. If you chose a different default port during installation, you of course should use that port number instead of 5432.

`sudo kill -15 <process id>`

2. With that list, you can run this command to end the Postgresql server process. The process id can be found in the PID column of the output.

Comment: I think this does not add anything new to the answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Go to project and click on docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
```

services:
web:
build: .
ports:
- "8000:8000"
volumes:
- .:/app
links:
- db
- mail-server
db:
image: "postgres"
environment:
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: hunter2
ports:
- "5432:9432"
mail-server:
image: "mailhog/mailhog"
expose:
- 1025
ports:
- "8026:8026"

"
change the ports to 8026:8026 because there is already running another container on this port number only change the port number"

Comment: change port No in your docker-compose file because you are running another one .run this command " docker-compose up --build"

Answer (score 0):

I tried to `sudo kill -9 <PID>` to disable postgres process, but it spawns again and again with a different PID. After that, I found that it stores a process under `LaunchDemos` and it runs on every startup:

- `cd /Library/LaunchDemos/`
- `sudo rm com.edb.launchd.postgresql-13.plist`
- Restart your PC to apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

1)First you have to compose down:

```
`docker compose down`
```

2)Then, check if still listens:

`sudo lsof -i: 5432`

3)If you spot any user, you can kill with:

`lsof -t -i tcp:5432 | xargs kill`

4. Also you can get some helper, If all of these codes confused you.
   Install freeport:   `pip install freeport`

5)Then use it: `freeport 5432`

This will close every port listener and established user.

6. Also a big reminder:
   Some of the Mac apps use ports, for example port 5000 is used in many MACOS for AirPlay Receiver, you can disable it from Settings>AirPlay Receiver> Turn Off if you are using a MacBook.
7. In the worst case scenario, shift the port written in your project.