# Cannot start service postgres: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am tryning to dockerize my rails application and I've already tried everything including restarting my postgres, restarting docker, removing all containers and images, removing networks, volumes, literally nuking everything relatied to docker but nothing helped.

When I do `docker-compose up` I get an error

```
ERROR: for rails-rest-api_postgres_1  Cannot start service postgres: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint rails-rest-api_postgres_1 (6211b1f9b1dc688472760c389cc0684542c89cf8afee7dce7c90032f65c58511): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
```

```
lsof -i :5432
```

doesn't return anything

I've literally everything from this post https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4126 and nothing helped.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.4-alpine as base

RUN echo "@edge http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add build-base && apk --no-cache add \
  tzdata \
  bash \
  git \
  libstdc++ \
  ca-certificates \
  libffi-dev \
  postgresql-dev \
  postgresql-client \
  linux-headers \
  libpq \
  openssh \
  file \
  libxml2-dev \
  curl \
  gmp-dev \
  musl \
  gcompat \
  aws-cli@edge \
  shared-mime-info \
  libucontext-dev \
  && echo ‘gem: --no-document’ > /etc/gemrc

ARG IMAGE_TAG
ENV IMAGE_TAG=$IMAGE_TAG

RUN mkdir -p /app/vendor/gems
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

RUN gem install bundler:2.2.24

RUN bundle config set --local deployment 'true'
RUN bundle config set --local without 'development test'
RUN bundle config --delete without
RUN bundle config --delete with
RUN bundle install

COPY . /app

RUN RAILS_ENV=staging \
    DATABASE_URL=postgres:null \
    SECRET_KEY_BASE=blah

ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

# Deploy Image
FROM base as deploy
RUN rm -rf /root/.ssh

# Dev Image
FROM base as dev

RUN bundle install --with development

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk --no-cache add \
  curl-dev \
  postgresql \
  && echo ‘gem: --no-document’ > /etc/gemrc

RUN rm -rf /root/.ssh

# CI Image
FROM base as ci
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk --no-cache add \
  curl-dev \
  postgresql \
  && echo ‘gem: --no-document’ > /etc/gemrc

RUN bundle install \
  --with test \
  --deployment

RUN rm -rf /root/.ssh

COPY config/database.ci.yml config/database.yml
```

Comment: That error message almost always means you have some other PostgreSQL server running, either directly on the host or in another Docker setup.  You can change the first `ports:` number (but not the second) or often can remove the `ports:` block entirely.  Also see [Docker Error bind: address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971961/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use) or [Docker & Postgres: Failed to bind tcp 0.0.0.0:5432 address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249434/docker-postgres-failed-to-bind-tcp-0-0-0-05432-address-already-in-use).

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this issue.
[image]

1. sudo services postgresql stop # or sudo systemctl stop postgresql
2. docker-compose up
3. It works for you
   [image]